# How does scrcpy sync the clipboard?

Tags: android, bash, adb, clipboard

When I copy something to my clipboard on my computer and press CTRL+V in the scrcpy screen, it paste the very thing to my Android device I just copied to the clipboard on my computer. For automation purposes I'm looking for a way to do the same thing using a bash script.

I read about the program Clipper, but since this is currently not installed on my Android device it's not the way scrcpy does the trick and so there has to be another way.

The next thing I tried was using shell input. The example below worked

```
text=$(escape_text "${text}") 
adb shell input text "$text"
```

However, when the text contained Unicode characters, this code didn't work anymore.  Next I tried copying text to the clipboard, while scrcpy was running in the background, hoping it would sync the clipboard for me.

```
printf %s "${text}" | xclip -i -selection clipboard
adb shell input keyevent 279 #paste
```

This code didn't work (with or without Unicode characters), since the clipboard wasn't automatically synced.

So my question is, how does scrcpy sync the clipboard (including Unicode characters) and is this possible to do so from a bash script?

I'm currently testing this with an Android 9 device, but it would be nice to find a solution that also works on newer Android versions.

Comment: You may want to read the original blog post describing scrcpy: https://blog.rom1v.com/2018/03/introducing-scrcpy/ and note the section on 'Text Input'. Also https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/FAQ.md#special-characters-do-not-work

Comment: @MorrisonChang This is a great start and I successfully rewrote it in to bash code. However, when testing this, I realized that the E with circumflex and dot below (Ệ) is missing. I expected scrcpy not being able to handle this character as well (as my code did), but after copy pasting text with this special E it pasted it correctly, So there must be more to it then this code I just converted into bash code. Am I missing something here? https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/v1.0/server/src/main/java/com/genymobile/scrcpy/KeyComposition.java

Comment: @MorrisonChang Found out scrcpy actually has a way to set the clipboard, pretty interesting! https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/v2.1.1/server/src/main/java/com/genymobile/scrcpy/wrappers/ClipboardManager.java